# Puzzling REST controller mapping

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have a REST controller with a few mappings:

```
@RequestMapping(params = {"technicianId", "teamId"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<TeamTechnicianResource> findByTeamAndTechnician(@RequestParam(value = "teamId", required = true) Long teamId, @RequestParam(value = "technicianId", required = true) Long technicianId, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    logger.debug("============>>> teamId: " + teamId + " technicianId: " + technicianId);
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    TeamTechnician foundTeamTechnician = teamTechnicianService.findByTeamAndTechnician(teamId, technicianId);
    TeamTechnicianResource teamTechnicianResource = teamTechnicianResourceAssembler.toResource(foundTeamTechnician);
    responseHeaders.setLocation(builder.path(UriMappingConstants.PATH_SEPARATOR + UriMappingConstants.TEAM_TECHNICIANS).queryParam("teamId", teamId).queryParam("technicianId", technicianId).buildAndExpand().toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<TeamTechnicianResource>(teamTechnicianResource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(params = "technicianId", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<TeamTechnicianResource>> findByTechnician(@RequestParam(value = "technicianId", required = true) Long technicianId, Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<TeamTechnician> pagedResourcesAssembler, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    Page<TeamTechnician> foundTeamTechnicians = teamTechnicianService.findByTechnician(technicianId, pageable);
    responseHeaders.setLocation(builder.path(UriMappingConstants.PATH_SEPARATOR + UriMappingConstants.TEAM_TECHNICIANS).queryParam("technicianId", technicianId).queryParam("page", pageable.getPageNumber()).queryParam("size", pageable.getPageSize()).buildAndExpand().toUri());
    Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(TeamTechnicianController.class).findByTechnician(technicianId, pageable, pagedResourcesAssembler, builder)).withRel("findByTechnician");
    PagedResources<TeamTechnicianResource> teamTechnicianPagedResources = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(foundTeamTechnicians, teamTechnicianResourceAssembler, selfLink);
    return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<TeamTechnicianResource>>(teamTechnicianPagedResources, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(params = "teamId", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<TeamTechnicianResource>> findByTeam(@RequestParam(value = "teamId", required = true) Long teamId, Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<TeamTechnician> pagedResourcesAssembler, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    Page<TeamTechnician> foundTeamTechnicians = teamTechnicianService.findByTeam(teamId, pageable);
    responseHeaders.setLocation(builder.path(UriMappingConstants.PATH_SEPARATOR + UriMappingConstants.TEAM_TECHNICIANS).queryParam("teamId", teamId).queryParam("page", pageable.getPageNumber()).queryParam("size", pageable.getPageSize()).buildAndExpand().toUri());
    Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(TeamTechnicianController.class).findByTeam(teamId, pageable, pagedResourcesAssembler, builder)).withRel("findByTeam");
    PagedResources<TeamTechnicianResource> teamTechnicianPagedResources = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(foundTeamTechnicians, teamTechnicianResourceAssembler, selfLink);
    return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<TeamTechnicianResource>>(teamTechnicianPagedResources, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The first mapping with the two parameters responds fine when requested only if the third mapping with the teamId parameter is not present in the controller.

Otherwise, the exception is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.MediaType.compareTo(Lorg/springframework/http/MediaType;)I
```

The second mapping with the technicianId always responds fine when requested.

And the third mapping with the teamId always responds fine when requested.

I'm using Spring 4.0.7.RELEASE and Security 3.2.5.RELEASE on tomcat 7.

Any clue ?

Comment: **What URLs** do you want each method to respond for? *(Btw, your controller knows too much, I'd move some of that logic to the service, keeping the controllers as thin as possible. Are you testing these methods? The tests would "scream" what I'm trying to say.)*

Comment: The urls are indicated ny the mappings. Say: teamtechnicians?technicianId=1&teamId=1 My controller handlers are calling their services. I can't see the headers or resources assemblers being part of the services. What else would you see in services ?

Comment: I just tried something. I renamed the teamId parameter into a myteamId parameters on the third controller handler and now all handlers work fine. I can't believe this issue is coming from the name of the parameter. What gives ?

Comment: Tried something else. I renamed the teamId parameter into a myteamId parameters on the first controller handler and now all handlers work fine too.

Comment: This thing smells like a JIRA to me now. What do you reckon ?

Comment: It could be, it is hard to tell - maybe the docs state that it is not allowed, the only way to know is to research or, well, open the ticket. But, in the meanwhile, why don't you keep only one method (the first) and dispatch inside it according to what was received?

Comment: About the controllers, you are right, I stand corrected. I said that based on a quick look only: I saw more than one `findBy*` and some cluttered code and jumped into that conclusion. Layer-wise your code seems OK (the tests - or better, the testability - would give the final say), but, if I may, I'd still suggesting some method extracting and such, it'd help the readability. Cheers!

Comment: I wonder what you mean by using method extracting to improve readability.

Comment: The ["Extract Method" refactoring](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html). Have you seen the book "Clean Code"? I don't understand your code much, but here's an attempt to make it more readable: https://gist.github.com/acdcjunior/9ca2c90138985fe7ca47 check the last method, see how it is less confusing, now showing better the steps its processing takes, as each step is now represented by a method call. Of course, this attempt of mine is very simplistic, as I don't understand your code. You could do a lot better. The next step would be reusing some of those methods and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the gist. Looks neat indeed. I shall give it a go later on when I have more time. I also logged a JIRA at https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the JIRA issue, this is not a framework problem but rather a dependency management one.

In this project, multiple (and incompatible!) versions of Spring Framework are on the classpath: 3.2.8 and 4.0.7. Using [Spring Framework's "Bill Of Materials"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-maven-bom) is a nice way to prevent those issues in the future.